# SQL Count element and group on element

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a view that counts an element and groups it based on a different element.

My table looks something like this

|  | Source | Material | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Src1 | A123456 | Dest2 |
| 2 | Src1 | A658979 | Dest1 |
| 3 | Src1 | B123456 | Dest1 |
| 4 | Src1 | B658979 | Dest1 |
| 5 | Src1 | C123456 | Dest2 |

Description of what I am trying to archive:

Count the materials that start with "A" as "Count Material A" and start with "B" as "Count Material B" and group by destination.

Based on the table above the result should look something like that:

|  | Count Material A | Count Material B | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Dest1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | Dest2 |

For now I am only able to succesfully create the query for the counting part but I cannot figure out how to base the counting on the destination as well.

NOTE: I think I know how to do it when I "hardcode" the destination in the where-clause but it is expected that there will be more destinations in the future so I am trying to future-proof this solution.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why for `ID 2`, the `Destination` is `Dest2` and not `Dest1`? What is the logic? You need to show us your query so we can help you with it

Comment: How do you count materials?

Comment: I could suggest to use a group by on Destination and on the first letter of Material and return the count, then use the Pivot function to create the materials columns.

To simplify the query you could also use the WITH statement, in this way you can split the various stage of the query in simpler parts

Ref. [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16), [WITH common_table_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It seems like it's a mistake the ID column should appear in the result?

Comment: Yes I made a mistake here. ID is not really an ID I just wanted to add a row count so it can be used as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    Destination,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Material LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 END) AS [Count Material A],        
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Material LIKE 'B%' THEN 1 END) AS [Count Material B]
FROM yourTable
WHERE Material LIKE 'A%' OR Material LIKE 'B%'
GROUP BY Destination;
```

Comment: Consider to add WHERE LEFT(Material,1) IN ('A','B') to reduce the execution time